# Can a good answer be reason enough to reopen a closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/what-micro-controller-should-i-use) question was recently asked, and despite it's opinion-based nature I tried to answer it with the most factual answer I could. However, it got `closed as primarily opinion-based.`

I can understand why, but in the small description below is says:

```
answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
```

I feel that [my answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/what-micro-controller-should-i-use/2153#2153) was sufficiently based on `facts and references`, and that the question is now valid. My answer provides enough good information to help someone make a decision, and has little/no opinion in it.

Basically I want to know if having a good answer to a closed question can merit it a reopen. I think it should, as the answer could be helpful to others, assuming it is well written and not opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question. If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the [on hold] notice automatically changes to [closed]. There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but **they both allow comments, votes and edits**.

That means a closed question will still show up in the search results and can be voted upon (no difference in rep either, as far as I am aware). Leaving it closed, in my opinion, serves the double purpose of preserving the answer for future visitors while still showing them that this is not the type of question that should be asked.

It is true that a closed question becomes eligible for deletion but it will only be [deleted automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/193737) for the following reasons

> 1. The system will automatically delete any post flagged six times as offensive or spam.
> 2. The system will will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.
> 3. The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days.
> 4. The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.
> 5. The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.
> 6. The system will automatically delete questions migrated to other sites after 30 days.

So your answer should be safe unless people explicitly flag the question for deletion.